# Add current date/time to ps output

Tags: log, ps

I want to log my cpu and memory usage.  There are loads of posts out there giving different options using `ps`, `top`, `python`, etc.  I really like the `ps` way of doing it.  In my case, I call:

```
ps -o user -o pid  -o pmem -o pcpu -u dxd9163
```

Which gives a nice table:

[image]

Because I'm logging this data (every ten minutes), I would like to add the date/time information to each row of the table as with:

```
date +%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M
```

I don't want the process time, how long it was running or when it was started, I just want the time the snapshot was taken.  So in the figure above, a new field, `time` would be there with all the same info for each snapshot.

It seems the `ps` function has a deprecated option that may have worked before but doesn't anymore (`utime`).

Any idea how to do this?  It's probably easy but I'm new to Linux.

My final goal is to log every 10 minutes for as long at it takes into a `usage.txt` file ram and cpu usage for my user.

Comment: Did you look at `atop`, it seems closer to the info you'll get by repeatedly calling `ps`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick is to replace each *"start of line"* 
with *"start of line, timestamp "*:

```
ps -o user -o pid  -o pmem -o pcpu -u dxd9163 | sed "s#^#$(date +%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M) #"
```

Usually `sed`'s *substitute* operator uses a slash as separator (`s/…/…/`) but since
the timestamp already contains slashes, this won't work. I thus used a different 
separator (`s#…#…#`).